# Do all Unity events execute on component A before any events execute on component B

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two moving spheres with trigger colliders attached to each.  I'm moving the spheres in `Update`, and then checking for collision in `OnTriggerEnter`.

I'm doing a sphere sweep test to predict if the two spheres will hit each other.  The prediction is working correctly, except in the case that the two spheres will barely touch.  In that situation, my sweep test says that the spheres will not touch, but `OnTriggerEnter` is firing, so the spheres do actually touch.

One of my guesses for this erroneous behavior is that Unity might be calling sphere A's `Update`, then calling sphere A's `OnTriggerEnter` before it calls sphere B's `Update`.  In that case, the sphere sweep test would not be completely accurate since movement is not happening simulateously.

Looking at [Unity's Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), I'm unclear whether that order of events that's shown means that `Update` is called on *every* component before subsequent functions are called, or whether the entire sequence of events will be called for component A before *any* events are called for component B during a specific frame.

Does `Update` run for every component before any other events are called, or does component A execute all of its events (`Update`, `OnTriggerXXX`, `LateUpdate`, etc.) before the next component executes any events?

Comment: maybe use 2 scripts. Script 1 will have the Update function and Script 2 the OnTriggerEnter or whatever function you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this serve as an answer but was too big to explain it on a comment.

I was curious about your statement and I made the test: build 2 shperes that allow collisions (rigidbodies, colliders..) and put a simple script inside bouth of them.

```
public class SphereTest : MonoBehaviour
{    
    void Update()
    {
        print("Update in " + this.gameObject.name);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        print("OnTriggerEnter in " + this.gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

Then I move the first sphere (sphere) to the second one (sphere(1)) and the log result is this one:
[image]

The result is exactly the same if you move the second sphere instead of the first one.

So it seems that:

1. Yes, first are called all the update functions, then the events will
   pop-up, and so on.
2. The order of physics events are like the Update ones,
       arbitrary.

Anyways I recommend you to use `FixedUpdate` instead of `Update` if you try to work with physics.

Answer (score 1):

All the functions listed in unity's documentation will execute for all valid components before going to the next function. For the order at which each components gets the call there's a few things to keep in mind.

-You can force an actual order [per script](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html).

-Inside unity's editor the call order should be the same as the hierachy.

-In a build this order will vary so best not to rely on that.

Also like Lotan said if you have objects using unity physics you should do all physics action inside FixedUpdate because the only there you get unity to calculate collisions and such. If its moved in update, the collisions will only get calculate in the next physic's loop.

Often times when you want to move a bunch of objects it easier to manage using some sort of MovingManger that calls functions on each individual objects instead of each object hooking up to updates. That way you always know the order each sphere has and that usually more efficient and easier to implement things like pooling.